# Не удается получить значение из span

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, веб-программирование

Необходимо получить значение из тега span в input, помогите, пожалуйста:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var span = document.getElementById('total-price');
  var input = document.getElementById('of_total_price');
  input.val(span.innerHTML);
  var value = parseInt(input.val());
  console.log(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="total">Итого: <span id="total-price" name="total_price"></span>pуб.</div>
<input type="hidden" id="of_total_price" name="of_price" />
```

Comment: `<span id="total-price" name="total_price"></span>` у вас пустой...

Comment: А так...найдите элемент по id  и обратитесь к его свойству value...ничего сложного...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Необходимо получить значение из тега span в input

Как вариант - сделать так.

```js
$(_ => {
  var span = $('#total-price').text();
  var input = $('#of_total_price');
  input.val(span);
  var value = +input.val();
  console.log(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="total">Итого: <span id="total-price" name="total_price"></span>pуб.</div>
<input type="hidden" id="of_total_price" name="of_price" />
```